# Concurrent atomic select-update

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

How can I, using sqlalchemy, do something like this?

```
user = session.query("select * from user")
if user.state == "active"
    session.query("update user set state = 'inactive' where id = %d" % user.id)
```

I need the select and update to be one atomic operation. Another program should not be able to select/update the user while the operation is going.

How can I do it concurrently?

Note: I need to know if we succeeded in change the state or not.

How can I achieve that?

Am I doing it wrong?

Should it be a stored procedure?

Should I use database "lock"?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting an [isolation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels) of Serializable, which can be [done on a specific session with SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels) using `session.connection(execution_options={'isolation_level': 'SERIALIZABLE'})`. If two connections conflict (they both read before the other wrote), committing the transaction will fail, and you can just loop until it goes through.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.types import Boolean, Integer, String


Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)


url = 'postgresql://postgres@localhost/test'
engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)
if not engine.dialect.has_table(engine.connect(), 'users'):
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    session.add(User(name="remram", active=True))
    session.commit()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
session.connection(execution_options={'isolation_level': 'SERIALIZABLE'})  # Commenting this line will make this unsafe in a concurrent environment

user = session.query(User).filter(User.name == "remram").one()
if user.active:
    user.active = False
raw_input()  # So you can run this twice
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports **SELECT FOR UPDATE**
 (ie: PostgreSQL) you could use:

```
user = session.query("select * from user where id = %d for update" % theId)
if user.state == "active"
    session.query("update user set state = 'inactive' where id = %d" % user.id)
```

Comment: Doesn't this still allows select in between the 2 sql functions, thus It could update the state twice (the important part is not that I update twice, it's that what follows (after the update) is executed only once.

Comment: SELECT FOR UPDATE lock the row so that only the current transaction is allowed to modify it. Other transactions can SELECT it, but they will block if they try a SELECT FOR UPDATE, UPDATE or DELETE. It acts as a semaphore so that this section of code can only be executed by one transaction at a time.