# Flask-Sqlalchemy and horizontal scaling and scoped session

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, horizontal-scaling

I've app in flask-sqlalchemy and I want to scale horiontally

```
@app.route('/read')
def read():
    e = db.session.query(Example).get(1)
    return e.value, 200


@app.route('/increase')
def increase():
    e = db.session.query(Example).get(1)
    e.value += 1
    db.session.add(e)
    db.session.commit()
    return e.value, 200
```

There is two endpoints:

read - getting entity with id = 1 and getting value

increase = getting entity with id = 1 and increasing value

And then I want to scale horizontally, and flask-sqlalchemy doesn't synchronize session between workers. So even I increase value in worker 2, There is no way to get actual value from worker 1

example user requests:

```
curl GET /read/ [worker-1]
1


curl GET /increase/ [worker-2]
2


curl GET /read/ [worker-1]
1
```

As you see, sqlalchemy does not provide tools for automatically refreshing session state.

What is best way to fix this? Using new session for new queries? or use `session.refresh(instance)`. What is recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to tear down the session after each request. The [page on SQLAlchemy from the Flask website](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/) offers this snippet:

```
from yourapplication.database import db_session

@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db_session.remove()
```

Even then, concurrent edits to the same object are not safe. If you want your select-update to be atomic, you will need to change the isolation level on your session (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45291302/711380)).

Comment: The other option is to use flask-sqlalchemy yes. It is also recommended by Flask on that page I linked. That would most certainly solve the problem.